# Count random zero's in a data frame python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a big data frame. Below is the few sample example like -

DF -

| Seller | Jan-02 | Feb-02 | Mar-02 | Apr-02 | May-02 | Jun-02 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SellerA | 2 | 0 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 17 |
| SellerB | 12 | 0 | 30 | 0 | 40 | 45 |
| SellerC | 100 | 150 | 0 | 0 | 275 | 300 |
| SellerD | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| SellerE | 10 | 22 | 40 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| SellerF | 100 | 12 | 11 | 22 | 0 | 0 |
| SellerG | 10 | 70 | 100 | 121 | 21 | 22 |
| SellerH | 7 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 21 |
| SellerI | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I need the following seller list-

**Always 0** - Count of seller = 2 ; eg [ SellerD, SellerI]

**Show 0  in last 3 dates** - Count of seller = 1 ; eg [SellerE ]

**Sometimes 0** - Count of seller = 3 ; eg - [SellerA,SellerB,SellerC]

**Never 0** - Count of seller = 2 ; eg - [SellerG,SellerH]

Comment: Take a look at `df.eq(0).all(1)` , `df.eq(0).any(1)` etc. Try varying `.eq` with `.ne`, or filtering with `.loc` for the dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
tmp = df.set_index('Seller').eq(0)

df['Seller'].set_axis(
    np.select([tmp.all(axis=1), tmp.iloc[:, -3:].all(axis=1), tmp.any(axis=1)],
              ['Always 0', '0 in last 3 dates', 'Sometimes 0'], 'Never 0')
).groupby(level=0).count()
```

Or:

```
pd.Series(np.select([tmp.all(axis=1), tmp.iloc[:, -3:].all(axis=1), tmp.any(axis=1)],
          ['Always 0', '0 in last 3 dates', 'Sometimes 0'], 'Never 0')).value_counts()
```

Output:

```
0 in last 3 dates    1
Always 0             2
Never 0              2
Sometimes 0          4
Name: Seller, dtype: int64
```

If you want the lists:

```
df['Seller'].set_axis(
    np.select([tmp.all(axis=1), tmp.iloc[:, -3:].all(axis=1), tmp.any(axis=1)],
              ['Always 0', '0 in last 3 dates', 'Sometimes 0'], 'Never 0')
).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Output:

```
0 in last 3 dates                               [SellerE]
Always 0                               [SellerD, SellerI]
Never 0                                [SellerG, SellerH]
Sometimes 0          [SellerA, SellerB, SellerC, SellerF]
Name: Seller, dtype: object
```